# Closure returns what is supposed to and also undefined

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm practicing closures and my assigment for now is to :

> Write a function `once` that accepts a callback as input and returns a function. 
>   When the returned function is called the first time, it should call the callback 
>   and return that output. If it is called any additional times, instead of calling 
>   the callback again it will simply return the output value from the first time it 
>   was called.

My callback is:

```
const addByX = function (num1) {
    let number = num1;
    function adding(num2) {
        console.log(number + num2);
    }
    return adding;
}
//addByX(2)(8);

let addByTwo = addByX(2);
```

And my main function is:

```
const once = function (func) {
    let isFirst = true;
    let firstOutput;
    function inside(numberToPass) {
        if (isFirst) {
            firstOutput = func(numberToPass);
            isFirst = false;
            return func(numberToPass);
        } else {
            return firstOutput;
        }
    }
    return inside;
}
```

It works, but when I invoke it

```
const onceFunc = once(addByTwo);
console.log(onceFunc(4));  //should log 6
console.log(onceFunc(10));  //should log 6
```

it returns my values and also undefined.

And I really can't understand why would it.
Maybe if it works I should not ask this kind of questions, but I'm really curious. 
Debugger couldn't clearly answer my question.
I'm suspicious it has something to do with console.log, as abvious as it looks.

[Here in JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/pejucahuxa/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `addByX` returns another function, `adding`. But `adding` doesn't return anything; it just logs. It's return value is undefined.

I think you intended it to look like this:

```
const addByX = function (num1) {
    let number = num1;
    function adding(num2) {
        return number + num2;
    }
    return adding;
}
```

So the reason that it "worked" is because the callback was printing to the console, rather than where you are invoking it.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that :) But I've heard it's a good practice to reassigned input before operating on it